# How to use middleware for specific call in Django web app?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, middleware, django-middleware

I want to use middle ware in my django web app . But the problem is that i want to use middle ware only after user successfully login. I declare my custom middle ware in setting.py file but it's gives error because custom middle ware is called at unnecessary  restful call.  How do i call middle ware while some specific restful call.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed your middleware and the error you get. If you only want the code to run once when the user logs in, then using the [login signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals) might be a better option than middleware.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the user is active in django middleware apply in following way

```
class StackoverflowMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self,get_response):
        self.get_response=get_response

    def __call__(self,request):
        try:
            response=self.get_response(request)
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                print('Run when user Are login')
            else:
                print('Run when user Are not login')
        except Exception as e:
            self.process_exception(request,e)
        return response

    def process_exception(self,request,exception):
        print(exception.__class__.__name__)
        print(exception)
        return None
```

You also use `MiddleWareMixin` check user authentication

Comment: @meet you still face problem with `middleware`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the url path.

```
class YourMiddleware:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)
    if hasattr(request, 'path') and 'loggin-url' in request.path:
        # Do smthing

    return response
```